# Byte array to utf8 string

Tags: objective-c, string, ascii, byte

How do I get my byte array to a string that handles the Swedish letters å ä ö?

I do this at the moment:
NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", resData[i]];

(resData contains ascii characters)
But when I use the hexString in my output label I get jibberish for all non English chars.
How can I make a selected byte to an encode that handles the Swedish characters?

Regards
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

I don't get it.. from **NSString** reference you have:

```
- (id)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

so you should just do

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:resData 
                  length:yourLength
                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: but if I do it like that, how do I get a specific resData? I know the length of the whole resData array. for example, I want to get resData[i] and show it as a string.

Comment: you mean you want to convert just a character?

Comment: That wouldn't work. If your array is a byte array then many bytes will represent a single character in UTF8. You should first convert the whole array to a string and then extract single characters.. UTF8 has variable sized character so just getting the i-th wouldn't work

Comment: but if one byte represents one char then it is that char I need, and want to make it not jibberischy. Need to take one specific byte and turn it to utf8 or anything that can show å ä ö

Comment: as i already told you for example the angstrom has U+00C5 encoding in UTF8, this is 2 bytes not just one. You can't obtain it from just reading one byte each.

Comment: Its that I get my data from reading socket, didReadData, and one byte is one char, but with a oem charset. I have made a switch now as a fast solution where I hax out all åäöÅÄÖ, but will try the stated ones from you to get it better. Thanks for the fast replyes =)

Answer (score 2):

`resData` does NOT contain ASCII characters, because ASCII does not include characters for å, ä, and ö. If `resData` is a UTF-8 encoded string, then some characters (including these) are encoded using more than one byte.

It looks like you want a way to print the *n*th character. First, do as @Jack said and turn those bytes into an `NSString`:

```
/* Assuming |resData| is NULL-terminated and UTF-8 encoded... */
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:resData];
```

Now, to print the *n*th character of `text`:

```
NSUInteger n = 3;
NSString *character = [text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(n, 1)];
NSLog(@"character #%d: %@", n, character);
```

You can also set `character` as the string value of a control. It should display just fine.

The key take-away: `byte[i]` is NOT necessarily the same thing as the *i*th character. Text is always encoded, and you must always be (painfully) aware of that.